GCP Authentication using tokens
I have a desktop app and I want to use GCP cloud API. I want to authenticate using tokens. I first download the credentials andthen create a token file. Below is my code:
SCOPES =  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-language',
           'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
           'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
           'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
           'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write',
           'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control']


def get_document_credentials():
    
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
    if os.path.exists("token_document.json"):
      creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token_document.json", scopes)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
      if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
      else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            "credentials.json", SCOPES
        )
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
      # Save the credentials for the next run
      with open("token_document.json", "w") as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())
    
    return creds

creds = get_document_credentials()
# Instantiates a client
docai_client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(
    credentials=creds,
    client_options=ClientOptions(api_endpoint=f"{LOCATION}-documentai.googleapis.com")
)

However when I try to access api using the token I get the following error and then I have to re-authenticate.

Unauthenticated: 401 Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. [reason: "ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE_UNSUPPORTED"
metadata {
  key: "service"
  value: "documentai.googleapis.com"
}
metadata {
  key: "method"
  value: "google.cloud.documentai.v1.DocumentProcessorService.BatchProcessDocuments"
}

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong

The token of GCP is sometimes quite tricky, even when I didn't use this service before, but I had exp in some other tokens from GCP. Those will ask me to have the token set inside my environment. So that have a check in their Doc, or try to implement in your env. Hope this will help you.
